# Trying to select a date column in a table and removing the time from it at the same time?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am running this query

```
SELECT TO_DATE(datecol, 'YYYYMMDD', FALSE),

FROM table1

WHERE datecol BETWEEN '2020-12-01 00:00:01' AND '2021-06-01 00:00:01'
```

The `datecol` column is formatted like this "2021-05-17 14:07:11.061+00"

I want to select the datecol column but only the "2021-05-17" part. While at the same time only extracting data from December 2020 to July 2021.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't u use the ```TRUNC``` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it will work.

```
select datecol::date

FROM table1

WHERE datecol BETWEEN '2020-12-01 00:00:01'::timestamp AND '2021-06-01 00:00:01'::timestamp
```

`::date` - will convert the column from timestamp to date.

`::timestamp` - will convert the string to timestamp.

Can you please share what error are you reciving? Would be easier to help.